# Django 1.10 NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/ while following official django tutorial part 4

Tags: python, django

I am following Django Tutorial from it's official page. I am in part 4 of the tutorial. After writing results.html, detail.html and updating views according to it's documentation i get an error mentioned below while trying to access /polls/1 from browser. I can't find where the error lies as everything seems to be according to the tutorial. There's no error at /polls/ and polls/1/vote

NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/

Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P[0-9]+)/vote/$']

My polls/urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
url patterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),                                       
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

My detail.html file is

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action ="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}"/>
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

My results.html is as follows

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

and my polls/views.py file is

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from django.http import Http404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.template import loader

from .models import Choice, Question

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'queston':question})

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except(KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        #Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

My roots/urls.py file is

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/',include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Could you show the root `urls.py` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the context that gets rendered in your `detail` view. It's `question` and not `queston`.

In other words you are passing the `question` object as `queston` inside the `detail.html` template.

```
return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'queston': question})
```

It should be:

```
return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

Comment: Aren't they the same?? I can't seem to see any typo. Can you please elaborate the part where there is typo exactly

Comment: I have updated my answer to be more explicit.

Comment: Oh man, thanks a lot. You saved my day 